# New computer build powers up, fans spin but then slows to almost silent and wont display

Tags: display, computer-building, post

Apologies if this is a duplicate question.

I have built a new computer, and all cables appear to be in the correct place.
It powers up, the fans spin, there is a single short beep (like what you normally here on a computer) then the fans slow right down and I get no display on my monitor (which is actually a 42 inch television with a pc port).

I believe the graphics signal is sending as when cycling through the source options on my tv it picks up pc which it wouldnt if not connected.

I am using a 500w PSU coolermaster.
My motherboard is a gigabyte ga-b75-d3v (not the b75m-d3v version).
I have 8 gb of ddr3 1600mhz corsair vengeance ram (2*4gb sticks) (both sticks are in the white channels slots 1&3 I believe).
An intel i7 3770 CPU.
Normal onboard graphics as well as an old 256mb ATI GPU (cant tell you any more than that as I cannot identify further). I will add a Sapphire Radeon HD 7770 but have not connected it yet.
One corsair agility 3 ssd 120gb.

Could anybody advise me on what the issue may be and where I can start testing for issues?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you have the CPU power plugged in? Its a 4 or 6 pin plug right next to the processor - Half the time when someone asks me about similar issues, its that darned little thing.

Comment: There are three of these plugs on my PSU. One is a massive long strip. Thats in. I have two that have 4 pins/sockets, one is labelled as p1 this is inserted.

Comment: @jaget: Inserted into what?

Comment: inserted into a hole the same size. I followed the instruction manual. There is a socket with four holes to the left of the cpu. Its the only place it would fit and the Motherboard manual said to put it there.

Comment: remove ram and check for continuous beep sound & is it there any low glow of power light at motherboard when your fan getting slowed

Comment: Try to remove your video card and use the onboard video to see if it will show anything

Comment: I have tried both on board and GPU and have tried on board graphics with GPU removed. @vignesh I have removed ram and am getting continuos short beeps. What would this mean?

Comment: No, it should not be labeled p1 There should be a 20 pin connector with a 4 pin connector that hooks to it, there should also be a 4 pin socket thats got 2 black and 2 yellow connectors on it. The 4 pin p1 connector is an extention to a 20 pin power connector.

Comment: @if there's any continuous short beeps then your ram slot f your motherboard works fine,its the basic step to diagnose your motherboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you maybe forgot to connect the 4-pin ATX cable. This is not to be confused for the 4-pin additional connections on a 20+4 (or 24 pin) main power connector. There's still one more power connector that has 2 yellow (12-volt) wires and 2 black (ground) wires that needs to be connected to the motherboard in order for it to boot properly. (Older systems don't have this, but yours does!)

If you're sure the power supply is all connected then you might also look at your graphics card since some will require additional power as well. (This shouldn't be necessary for anyone with motherboard embedded graphics.)

Other than that, you might want to double check all connectors. I'd be willing to bet that something isn't connected correctly or the motherboard might not be properly mounted (as in not bolted/snapped-in properly).

If you can get into your BIOS settings (pressing the DEL key during power up) and it all shows up on whatever you're using for a monitor then you know power and most hardware is working. But it sounds like you can't get that far and that's why I strongly suggest inspecting all connections and mount points.

Comment: There was a four pin power cable missing. I had a 24 pin slot which on my PSU was split into a 20 and a 4 plug that fit neatly together. In addition my cables for my front controls (power, reset buttons etc) had some negative wires in positive and vice versa. I didn't realize white meant negative power. Thank you all for your prompt response. Now I just need to setup the OS :P

Answer (score 1):

You have a build in diagnostic tool - its the beeper. Your motherboard have instructions on what specific beep sequence means. You will find out this way on which step the POST is failing or which part of the PC have a problem.

Comment: According to the manual and the official gigabyte site, one short beep means POST has passed with no issues.

Comment: are you connecting the monitor to the onboard GPU card or to the external one? Can you try with the other one?